# How to instantiate logbook in spring boot app

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logbook

I have a simple Spring boot app with `logbook-spring-boot-starter` dependency of the [logbook](https://github.com/zalando/logbook) library.

The document says for ignoring health check request, wire up the logbook like this:

```
Logbook logbook = Logbook.builder()
    .condition(exclude(
        requestTo("/health"),
        requestTo("/admin/**"),
        contentType("application/octet-stream"),
        header("X-Secret", newHashSet("1", "true")::contains)))
    .build();
```

It may sound naive, But I don't know where should wire it up. Should I put it in any specific class or method with specific annotation? An example would help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is really simple. Just create a bean of the `Logbook` type in a `@Configuration` class:

```
@Configuration
public class LogbookConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Logbook logbook() {
        Logbook logbook = Logbook.builder()
            .condition(exclude(
                requestTo("/health"),
                requestTo("/admin/**"),
                contentType("application/octet-stream"),
                header("X-Secret", newHashSet("1", "true")::contains)))
            .build();
        return logbook;
    }
}
```

Of course, the specific library must be present on the classpath:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.zalando</groupId>
    <artifactId>logbook-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

The [README.md](https://github.com/zalando/logbook#spring-boot-starter), section Spring Boot Starter says the following and provides a table of configurable integration points.

> Every bean can be overridden and customized if needed